# FFMPEG image overlay zoompan leaving shadow

Tags: ffmpeg

I have the code for adding many images overlay to a video. It works fine, but since every overlay a white shadow of the image is kept until the end of the video, like this:

[image]
As you can see, a white shadow of all images is kept in the center of the image.

**This is my code:**

```
-i "input.mp4" -i "1.png" -filter_complex "[1:v]format=yuva422p,scale=7290x4850,setsar=1/1,pad=1.5*iw:1.5*ih:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:color=black@0,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0010,1.5)':s=729x485:d=400:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)',fade=in:st=0:d=3:alpha=1,fade=out:st=13:d=3:alpha=1,setpts=PTS+22/TB[im1];[0][im1]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h - overlay_h)/2" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy "output.mp4"
```

*(in that code I add only one image, but there might be more)*

Why this white shadow is kept since the overlay to the end of the video?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the fade duration indicates the interval it takes to carry out the effect. So the frame with the completed effect is only drawn after the interval e.g. for a one-second fade out at 25 fps, frame 1 has full intensity and frame **26** has zero intensity.

You have generated 400 frames with zoompan and specified a 3 second fade out starting at frame # 326. So frame 401 onwards will be blank. But you don't have a frame 401.

Either increase zoompan duration to `401` or decrease fade-out duration to `2.96`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help and the explaination!